# Git extensions is asking me to commit files that I didn't change - why?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand git using git extensions. Here is my scenario:

**Developer A** *(working in master branch)*

- Commit new files X,Y,Z to master branch

**Developer B** *(working in branch 1)*

- Pull from master branch into branch 1
- Resolved file conflicts (using
  theirs) for files X,Y,Z
- Committed merge to branch 1

**Developer C** (working in master branch)

- Change file P
- Commit and push to master branch
- Git extensions asks to pull so - pull & merge done

Un-staged files now have file P and files X,Y,Z in the commit

Surely I should only be committing my single file P change and not Developer B's merge changes (done in a different branch) as well?

Comment: Sounds like something about your scenario is incorrect. Did Dev B accidentally merge branch 1 into master?

Comment: No master was merged into branch 1.